# How to insert nested json in MySql using Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, postman

I am new to springboot and have just started learning.

My json file looks like this

```
{
 "users":[
{
  "index":"1",
  "name":"john doe",
  "number": "942856532",
  "ID":[ 
  {
    "username":"john_doe212",
    "email":"john_doe134@gmail.com"
  }
  ],
},
{
  "index":"2",
  "name":"jane doe",
  "number": "941856532",
  "ID":[ 
  {
    "username":"jane_doe212",
    "email":"jane_doe134@gmail.com"
  }
  ],
 }

]
}
```

I am trying to send a post request through postman to mysql where I have created two tables `Users` and `ID`.

Primary key of `Users` is `index` and ID is `id`.

Each table has the same columns as in the json.

"ID" table additionally has a column `user_id` which is the foreign key that links to the primary key of `Users` table.

What would be the best way to create the connection in spring that allows me to post this query that sends the values to both tables.

(I can make changes to the database if that is what's required) Also any advice on spring best practices would be helpful!

I've tried creating two entity classes and linking them through a @OnetoOne annotation which works only for the main json object "users" and all of its fields but not for the nested json object "ID"(always returns a null value).

Comment: I have to say, i dont see a good reason for having 2 tables in this case, unless a user could legitimately have more than one set of data that you place in the ID table

Comment: If 2 tables are not required how should I proceed? Add in two more columns for username and email? That should be ok but I'm still not sure how to access that nested json object(ID). I've tried using modelmapper but it still returns a null value.

Comment: If you were to create those 2 new columns, you would not need the object(ID)

Comment: Added the two columns to my entity class and database. Still cannot access the fields username and email.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but I suggest you ask another question. This time show us the code you are using to "access" these columns along with a schema and some example data